# Is Git only for Code or also for Data?

Tags: r, git

I am running into a bit of a dilemma and I was hoping to be pointed in the right direction.

I have Git repository which two (self-explanatory) folders: `scripts` and `data`. I keep adding new data files to analyze in `data`, while in `scripts` I write `R` scripts to analyze those files.

I track changes in both folders. Therefore, I commit additions of new data files to `data`. This has nothing to do with tracking changes. I just want the scripts and the data to move together since I work on at least two machines. 
I feel like I am using Git improperly, as (with respect to the `data` folder) I basically use it as a syncing tool.

**So my question**: is it bad habit to use Git also for data?

Comment: The main issue with keeping data in the repo is that each time you change the data, Git will make a new copy of it. If your dataset is large (say 100s of MB or GB), this can really blow out the size of your repo. If it's small, or you never modify it, then there's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are doing something particularly awful. Perhaps you could keep data on its own branch and then use it as a submodule or subtree?